# Filter datas between each other

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

How to filter datas between each other

I have `status.json`
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.9f445c216ad64d449264db22a749c57c

I get this array `product`
https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.47af6080e8dd414aafbd131c1a5c81b9

If `viewStatus === grid` filtered array `product` and should receive only `color` and `height` from `status.json`

If `viewStatus === inline` filtered array `product` with `color`, `size`, `capacity` from `status.json`

Array `product` can have more arrays

I try this to get objects from `status.json`

```
Object.entries(status).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
  if (key === variantValue.value) {
    value.accent.forEach(element => element.map(x => console.log(x)))
  }
})
```

I try to to get objects from `product`

```
product.map(element => console.log(element))
```

If `viewStatus === grid` https://jsoneditoronline.org/#left=cloud.332befaf0c104e9e9042c5ec69e22410

Comment: @trincot If i add the inputs (you mean JSON) I will getting an error when creating a question, because i have a lot of code. Why my structure has invalid? Im getting this structure from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got the idea correctly:

```js
const status = {
  "grid" : {
    "accent" : [
      [
        {
          "color" : "property"
        },
        {
          "height" : "property"
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "inline" : {
    "accent" : [
      [
        {
          "color" : "property"
        },
        {
          "size" : "property"
        },
        {
          "capacity" : "property"
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}


const product = [
   [
      "size",
      {
         "name":"Size",
         "code":"size",
         "propertiesList":[
            {
               "value":"50",
               "code":"50sm"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   [
      "capacity",
      {
         "name":"Capacity",
         "code":"capacity",
         "propertiesList":[
            {
               "value":"0.75",
               "code":"750ml"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   [
      "height",
      {
         "name":"Height",
         "code":"height",
         "propertiesList":[
            {
               "value":"Low",
               "code":"low"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   [
      "color",
      {
         "name":"Color",
         "code":"color",
         "propertiesList":[
            {
               "value":"Red",
               "code":"red"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
]

function getPropertyValue(product, key) {
  const item = product.find(item => item[0] === key)
  return item?.[1]?.propertiesList?.[0]?.value
}

function formatStatus(status, product, viewStatus) {
  // creating a deep copy to avoid mutating the original object
  const currentStatus = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(status[viewStatus]))
  currentStatus.accent[0].forEach(item => {
    for (const key in item) {
      item[key] = getPropertyValue(product, key)
    }
  })

  return { [viewStatus]: currentStatus }
}

console.log(formatStatus(status, product, "grid"))
```